# Error Handling with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, error-handling

Im new to spring MVC, Im used to using AJAX calls in javascript in order to make requests to server side and I usually just return a JSON string with a success flag and when needed an error message for the user to view.

Im not sure how to do something like this using Spring MVC, could someone show me a simple example or point me in the right direction please? I have a simple form right now and I just want to return a simple custom string message to the original form if a text field is left blank on submit!

I tried to follow a few examples that used  tags and  tags but my HTML pages didnt like this and I wasnt sure how to bind the message from server side either.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this [Spring tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)? It provides a step-by-step guide to something similar to what you are asking for. Pay special attention to `@ResponseBody` annotation.